# How to add additional functions based on Attribute Settings in Directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I am creating a custom directive for my Angular app that has a basic functionality. Along with the directive, I also want to add an attribute that works like an additional settings option so I can add extended functionality if an attribute is mentioned.

I want to do something like this:

```
 <div use-date-picker this-ngmodel="formData.dt" today></div>
```

In the above custom directive, I want the datepicker input field to have today's date only when the `today` attribute is added. Now, I dont know how to define the function in that directive so it adds the default todays date only when 'today' attribute is added to the DIV that is calling the directive. I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
app.directive('useDatePicker', function() { 

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            thisNgmodel: '='            
        },
        template: '<div class="input-group">' +         
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" name="dt" ng-model="thisNgmodel" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />' +
                  '</div>   ',        

        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log(scope.thisNgmodel);
            console.debug(scope);

            // Here I am trying to add the default Today's date if today attribute is added
            if (element.attr('today')) {
                $scope.today();
            }
        },

        controller: function($scope) {
                //DatePicker
                  $scope.today = function() {
                    $scope.thisNgmodel = new Date();
                  };


                // ....... etc.. etc.. with other controller settings .......
            }

    };
});
```

**Can I add extra functions to the directive template if an attribute is mentioned? What have I done wrong in the above code?**

Comment: is it working beside that improvement?

Comment: yeah.. other than that it is working. Also if I add `$scope.today();` inside the controller, it works. But having in controller will work for all fields as default. I only want to show this today's date when additional attribute is added when calling the custom directive. Thats why I removed it from the controller and trying to call this function for a specific attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**controller** attribute of directive is not same as `module.controller`. It's main purpose is communication with other directive's api... quote from angularjs docs

> **Best Practice:** use controller when you want to expose an API to other
>   directives. Otherwise use link

you can just set model's value to new date at link function...

```
if (element.attr('today')) {
   scope.thisNgmodel = new Date();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that and for quoting the best practice. I am still a little confused about the whole controller and directives thing. I usually use the controller to control the views. Only this case with the directive (its my first directive), I used this controller in it since it controls the functionality of this particular directive. So now, I will look into it and see if I need to change all of the controller functions to links.

Comment: And with your code of setting the model's value at link function, it didint work at first when I had `<div use-date-picker this-ngmodel="formData.dt" today></div>` in the view. Having it as plain `today` doesnt work. But once I change the `today` attribute in view to `today="true"`, it worked after that.

Comment: yes you are right you should look attribute value so it should have some value after all... anyway if you start recently to code directive be sure to understand all document... http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive this will help you so much...

Comment: I spent the past couple of days reading through the developers guide link you had given. It was very helpful. I had to re-read it a few times, try out different things in order to get a better understanding and grasping on how and when to use Directives. Thanks again for your support since it helped me with the learning. Much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome @blackops_programmer I am so happy if I can give something usefull to you, keep up good work, there are a lot of doing in angularjs... here is great repository https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning you can find many usefull resource about angular

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a typo on your end when posting your question, but in the linker function you 're passing in `scope` and then targeting `$scope`.

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    console.log(scope.thisNgmodel);
    console.debug(scope);

    // Here I am trying to add the default Today's date if today attribute is added
    if (element.attr('today')) {
      // $scope.today(); -- $scope doesn't live here. 
      scope.today();
    }
},
```

**Edit:**

Try this out:

```
attr.$observe('today', scope.today);
```

This should run the `scope.today` function if `today` has been assigned in the markup. Lemme know if this takes care of it.

Comment: Actually I wasnt sure if it was supposed to be `scope` or `$scope`. But I also tried it as `scope.today();` and that doesnt work neither.

Comment: Check my edited answer above. I'm thinking it might have to do with looking at `attr`, as opposed to the `element.attr` route.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer @Kasper Lewau. It shows the today's date when add `attr.$observe('today', scope.today);` instead of the `if (element.attr('today')) ` statement. However it shows the todays date even if `today` is not mentioned in the view directive though.